# Updating a git variable in the Shell prompt on every command

Tags: command-line, git, prompt, tcsh

I am running TCSH and I would like to update my prompt every time I run a command. I think can currently do that via backticks.

```
 set tmpstr = `git status --untracked-files=no --porcelain`

 set prompt="%{\e[35;1m%} $tmpstr %{\e[32;1m%}%n%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%~%{\e[37m%}"\$"%{\e[0m%} "
```

But I really don't want to have the full list of files every time. So just saying whether the GIT directory is clean is enough.

```
 set tmpstr1 = `git status --untracked-files=no --porcelain`

if ("$tmpstr" == "") then 
    set gitstr = 'Git: Clean'
else 
    set gitstr = 'Git: Uncommitted GIT ' 
endif 

 set prompt="%{\e[35;1m%} \$gitstr %{\e[32;1m%}%n%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%~%{\e[37m%}"\$"%{\e[0m%} "
```

But the gitstr won't be updated, as it isn't a command. Any one got any other ideas? Or any magical ways of calling a full if statement each time I run a command?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but you can use the special `postcmd` alias for this. [I do similar tricks with `cwdcmd`](https://bitbucket.org/Carpetsmoker/config/src/8fbc0c013bc6d35a0b755f979d04a8626a656901/modules/tcsh/tcsh/cwdcmd.tcsh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) to show the repo branch in my prompt (`alias cwdcmd source ~/.tcsh/cwdcmd.tcsh`). it's a bit ugly though, due to tcsh's shortcomings :-/

Comment: Hmm, I could assign $tmpstr in a script I call with cwdcmd? cwdcmd gets called every time I change a directory? Even if I don't call the alias in the prompt?

Comment: Yes, so you need to use `postcmd`. And the trick is to set the `prompt` from `postcmd`. Assigning variable is useless since `.tcshrc` isn't read.

Comment: Ok, i will update later with answer. @Carpetsmoker What is the difference between postcmd and precmd?

Comment: Read `man tcsh`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I did, I thought precmd ran before the prompt and would be the better one to use, as the other ran before the command execution. But you said postcmd was better. I was curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `precmd`

I put `alias precmd 'source ~/.tcsh/precmd.tcsh'` into my .cshrc file and moved my prompt set into that file.

Source of the .tcsh

```
set tmpstr = `(git status --untracked-files=no --porcelain >! ~/out ) >&! ~/out1`
#echo $tmpstr #for debugging
    if !( -s ~/out )  then 
        if !( -s ~/out1 ) then
            set gitstr = "Git: Clean"
            set prompt="%{\e[35;1m%} \$gitstr %{\e[32;1m%}%n%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%~%{\e[37m%}"\$"%{\e[0m%} "
        else
            #echo "not in GIT"
            set prompt="%{\e[35;1m%} %{\e[32;1m%}%n%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%~%{\e[37m%}"\$"%{\e[0m%} "
        endif
    else 
        set gitstr = "Git: Uncommitted GIT "
        set prompt="%{\e[35;1m%} \$gitstr %{\e[32;1m%}%n%{\e[37m%}@%{\e[33m%}%m%{\e[37m%}:%{\e[36m%}%~%{\e[37m%}"\$"%{\e[0m%} "
    endif
```

That allowed me to check when I am in get, and report the status back to the cmd line. When out of the GIT folder it just doesn't report GIT status. The shenanigans going on up in the tmpstr is to remove the stderror from the konsole.

Comment: Next I am going to write a script that shows whether the local GIT directory is behind # changes. So you know automatically whether to pull. Will update when I get a chance.